# Xpath to get complete <p> including <a>

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML Code:

```
<p class="article-text">Text1 <a href="LINK" target="_blank">LinkText</a> Text2.</p>
```

I want to extract the complete `<p>` text incl. the LinkText if there is some (not in all cases).

Expected: "**Text1 LinkText Text2.**"

I tried `(//p)[2]`

But it's only showing me "Text1" ending when `<a>` opens.

Also tried `(//p)[2]|(//p)[2]/child::node()`, but then it ends at the `</a>` and I don't know how to extract the rest of the `<p>`.

Also it might be no `<a>` in this `<p>` or it might be 2 `<a>`'s in it.

Comment: which language are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

Your `xpath` should be.

```
//p[@class='article-text']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `string()` function.

```
string(//p)
```

Or the more specific

```
string(//p[@class='article-text'])
```